How to create a timer to implement a code every several seconds (less than 30 seconds)?
I want to implement a code in the "background.js" file every several seconds less than 30 seconds (ex: 1, 5, 10 seconds).
I know there is something called alarms but it doesn't deal with seconds or as I know it doesn't deal with less than 30 seconds, so it's not suitable in my case.
// popup.js
const startBtn = document.getElementById("startBtn");
startBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    browser.runtime.sendMessage({ event: "onStart" });
})

// background.js
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((data) => {
  const { event, seconds } = data;
  if (event == "onStart") {
    browser.storage.local.get("seconds").then((data) => {
      console.log("Code here"); 
    });
  } 
});

What is the solution in my case?

The background script dies after 30 seconds, so you'll have to keep it alive (in Chrome) and use setInterval or setTimeout. Firefox may need a different hack. That's rather wasteful though (35MB). How will you actually use the timer, what for?

I want to refresh a specific page every n seconds.

The background script is fine then.

Do you use setInterval  and setTimeout in the "background.js" file are suitable for that purpose?

Yes. These are the only methods anyway.
